# How to get more information about a BadRequest error from a REST call

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, designer-workflow, sharepoint-rest-api

I am attempting to write a workflow that will copy a newly created list item from a list on a subsite to a logging list on the parent site. I must have done something wrong because my workflow is showing as complete but not copying the data and logging a BadRequest error in the workflow log. 
unhelpfully, it is not telling me anything more about the nature of the bad request.
Does anyone know how I can access the full error message?

Answer (score 0):

You could use fiddler to test the REST API. For more detailed information, refer to the article below.

[Calling SharePoint REST API with POST from Fiddler.](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/zsoltilles/2017/05/21/calling-sharepoint-rest-api-with-post-from-fiddler/)

And you also could check the characters in the call http web service action are correct. For more detailed information, refer to the article below.

[Bad Request (400) with the SharePoint 2013 / Online REST API? Maybe it’s just the semicolon.](http://www.andrewconnell.com/blog/bad-request-400-with-the-sharepoint-2013-online-rest-api-maybe-it%E2%80%99s-just-the-semicolon)